# How to add a label that implements a c++ interface?

Tags: c#, c++, wpf

I have very limited C# experience, so maybe it's an commonly made mistake, however, I could not find the answer in any other topics.

In my WPF applicationj I'm tried to create a label that inherists from a default WPF label and     implements an interface that is defined in a dll (managed c++). My goal would be to pass an instance of this object to c++ code and have it, without use of a seperate thread, update the UI.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows;

namespace WPFTest
{
    //my class : default WPF Label, C++ interface (dll)
    class ObservationResultLabel : Label, IObservationResult
    {
        Boolean od;

        public Boolean ObjectIsDetected(){
            return od;
        }
        public void setObservationResult(Boolean od){
            this.od = od;
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                this.InvalidateVisual();
            }));
        }
        protected override void  OnRender(
                System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext drawingContext){
            if (od){
                Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }else{
                Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
            base.OnRender(drawingContext);
        }
    }
}
```

But when trying to build I get a "A value of type 'ObservationResultLabel' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'UIElementCollection'." error. If I try the same thing with a C# interface, there's no error.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of developing WPF GUIs is by using the [Model-View-ViewModel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) pattern. Passing WPF elements into managed C++ libraries just to update their properties is something I would recommend against. Overriding OnRender() is also not recommended. I would suggest you to take a look at some WPF introductory tutorials, for example [this one](http://wpftutorial.net/). If you are going to develop in WPF, you will need to get familiar with the "WPF way of thinking", and the WPF Framework.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be that the C++ managed interface is using a managed C++ language feature that is not usable by c# or WPF, try to add [[CLSCompliant]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.clscompliantattribute%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) attribute to your c++ interface if you could and then try to compile and see what the compiler says. i would take what @HighCore said under consideration as well.